# log in details of kiopatrix (level 1)

Tags: linux

what is the default log in username and password for kiopatrix level 1?

I cannot log in the kiopatrix (level 1) beacsue there seems to be a default login username and password. and how can i change the uersername and password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username is john and the password is TwoCows2. This is the default username and password.